# Can't access django website on ec2 instance development server

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Here's how I try running my dev server (I've tried this with and without sudo, just to make sure):

```
python manage.py runserver ec2-##-##-###-##.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000
```

Here's my iptables listing:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state ESTABLISHED
```

Here's how I try calling it in my browser: ec2-##-##-###-##.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/

Any idea what's up? I'm using an Ubuntu micro instance.

Comment: Is port 8000 open in your security group?

Comment: Err how do I check that? I thought opening it in iptables meant opening it for everybody.

Comment: Ec2 has a firewall system that exists outside of the instance. You can change the rules via api or ec2 console.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't own the instance, but I'll ask the person who does to open the port. If that works, I'll be happy to upvote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EC2 uses a firewall system called security groups that exist outside of the instance. Ports need to be open in the security group to access them from outside. You can change the rules via API or with the EC2 console.